# Southern California Civi CRM Expert Wanted

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

We are huge fans of Civi CRM, but in order to really understand the benefits of the platform we would like to work with a veteran. Basically, we need a consultant to point us in the right direction and keep us from making critical mistakes.

Leave your contact information and we will contact your prior to the end of the week. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for professional services and not directly about the use or development of the software itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have a single (arguably) right answer, which is the stack exchange paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in CiviCRM.  This question is likely to be closed as it doesn't really fit into the [StackExchange format](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Instead, I would suggest that you look at the list of partners and contributors on the CiviCRM website and contact them directly:

[Find an expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Irvine, in Orange County. Contact info is:

Joe McLaughlin
joesmcl@gmail.com
cell: 518-405-9231

My contact info is also at my [CiviCRM.org partner page](https://civicrm.org/providers/Joe-McLaughlin) and see my [LinkedIn profile](https://www.linkedin.com/in/joe-mclaughlin-2a12a0133/)